# Mac OSx 10.5.2 and Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2 ....can it work together?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am newbie to iphone programming and trying to learn iphone programming.I need experts help.Please forgive me if its repeat question.

I have intel processor MacBook  with 2.5 GB memory.

Version of Mac OS X installed is : 10.5.2

I have downloaded Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2 from APPLE DEVELOPER site.

My Query is : Whether the OS will support the Xcode version or i need to upgrade OS.

I don't want to upgrade the OS.

Please suggest .

regards,
Sunny

Comment: if you've downloaded it, why don't you install it and try it?!

Comment: I agree.but as in windows OS if installation creates problem may need to format machine or reinstall OS sometimes.I am not sure about Mac and i don't want to take risk. As i don't have Installation CD readily available to me.Thanks for your query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to bring you the bad news, but you will need to upgrade your OS.

Specifically, you will need Snow Leopard 10.6.4 or later.

If you can get a really old version of XCODE/iOS SDK, you might be able to run it on 10.5.2. But they are not longer available in Apple's WebSite.

Comment: how do i upgrade the OS.Just clicking the update button in my macbook will do upgrading or i need to get new version from the APPLE.

Comment: you need the new version from apple(snow leopard), as 10.6 is for snow leopard and you have 10.5

Comment: You'll need to purchase a copy of 10.6 (Snow Leopard). Xcode 3.2 won't run on 10.5

Comment: Many thanks to Pablo and Abizem for the help.I have chat with my MAC Vendor he has upgradation CD and he will upgrade my OS to Snow Leopard 10.6                                  Can you suggest anything else i need to take care for start learning iphone programming.

Comment: @sunny - I'd suggest looking at the resources listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c

Comment: Thanks the resources are very usefull and i have started on it.